# React stateless component not updating initially when redux prop updates, but updates after unmount/remount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've got a stateless component that has two redux props: one state prop, and one dispatch prop.

It renders the state prop and fires off the dispatch prop, which makes an api call to populate the state prop.

```
const Component = ({ items, getItems }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getItems()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

When the component first renders, items is empty and it renders as empty. But I see the action finishing and updating the redux store. However, the component does not rerender and remains empty.

However, if I unmount the component and remount it (in my case by navigating to a different route using React Router), the items get updated and rendered.

Shouldn't the component rerender when the redux store updates the items prop?

Edit:
I've added the container component as well. I'm using typescript if that makes a difference which I assume it doesn't. And as for rendering, I just render the container component somewhere

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Component from 'components/dashboard/item/Component'
import { getItems } from 'actions/item'
import { ItemByIdType, RootState } from 'types'

interface StateProps {
  items: ItemByIdType
}

interface DispatchProps {
  getItems: () => any,
}

interface OwnProps {}

export interface IComponent extends StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps {}

const mapStateToProps: (state: RootState) => StateProps = (state: RootState) => {
  return {
    items: state.item.byId
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps: (dispatch: any) => DispatchProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return {
    getItems: () => dispatch(getItems()),
  }
}

const ComponentContainer = connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Component)

export default ComponentContainer
```

Comment: Can you show how you're rendering this component and how you're connecting to Redux

Comment: Can you possibly share your entire component code, including how you map state and dispatch to props when connecting your component to your redux store? It may also be helpful to go ahead and include the reducers (and selectors if you use them) so we have a clear idea of how data is flowing through your app. Components *do* rerender when state or props update, but if you aren't returning **new** object references in your reducer (really easy to *not* do with arrays) then react reconciliation will miss those updates.

Comment: In the reducer, are you creating a new array for the items or adding them to the existing one?

Comment: ooooookay I found the mistake. I was mutating the state in my reducer. Thanks izambl and everyone else